Github Pages: React website custom URL causes empty webpage
I have created a custom URL for my react website on Github Pages but it just shows a black page.
Here is the repo for my website.
https://github.com/AdvancedRoboticCombat/website
I've configured the DNS settings as outlined by GitHub pages as below:

The DNS check on GitHub pages was successful.

Yet the website looks like this:
https://socal-arc.com
Before I used the custom URL the website functioned properly like below.

So I'm not sure what the issue is. Thanks for the help!

The browser fails to get the js and css resources within the directory static. Maybe you have to configure, that access to that directory and the subdirectories is granted. Maybe that's possible in the GitHub settings, or otherwise with an .htaccess file.

I don't think I have a static directory

It's inside the build directory.

oh I see it, I'll take a look
